# javascript disable input image submit button triggered before click event in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome

I'm working on disabling the submit button after the first click to avoid form submission errors. Due to the way I have validation set up if the form is submitted twice the 'hash' will be checked twice throwing an error.
the following code works in all browsers except Chrome

```js
function submitHandler() {
 var submit = document.getElementById('subImage');
        if (submit) {
     submit.addEventListener('click', submitClick, false);
        }
}

function submitClick() {
    this.disabled=true;
    return true;
}
```

If I comment out this.disabled=true; the form submits fine so it appears that the image button is disabled before an event is triggered. any help on this will be greatly appreciated.
 the submit is an input image.

```
<input type="Image" id="subImage" src="Images/Submit.gif" alt="Submit">
```

Comment: Minor note, for the `document.getElementById('subImage');`, do you mean `document.getElementById('subImage').value;`?

Comment: Can you add your html code?

Comment: azem Hagrass. <input type="Image" id="subImage" src="Images/Submit.gif" alt="Submit">. I can't add much beyond that, my site is OO so its mostly generated code, the code html/css is validated often so its clean.

Comment: Xero. I don't know how to reply directly to comments. but anyway there is no value, its an image input.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it over chrome and it works, here is the full code:

```
<html>
<body>
 <input type="Image" id="subImage" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-H3PYmWMurJA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAABIvA/7qNBlhQEC2s/s120-c/photo.jpg" alt="Submit">
<script>
function submitHandler() {
    var submit = document.getElementById('subImage');
        if (submit) {
        submit.addEventListener('click', submitClick, false);
        }
}

function submitClick() {
    this.disabled=true;
    return true;
}
submitHandler();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if its working for you maybe there's other code interfering with it. although there is no other JS code that deals directly with the submit. yeah your code doesn't work either, is it not bad practice to have variables outside of functions?

Comment: @Lydiaschubert: I know that this is not a good practice but it will helps a lot in understanding what we are dealing with. Can you alert this.disabled attribute each time on submit?

Comment: @Lydiaschubert: Just send me your code to me@hazemhagrass.com to check the whole document and I will check it then respond in a minutes